# how to get all shipping port name based on countries as sql server table?

Tags: c#, sql

how to get all shipping port name assoiciated with a country as sql server table?.i need all shipping port name in all countries .also, is it possible to get as sql server table.I got country list as sql query.i want to use this ship name to display in a combo box of C# windows application based on country.

Comment: Show your table structure. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Show us your table for country and shippingport i guess you have this 2 tables

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 2 table
Country Table

CountrID = int

ContryName = Varchar

Port Table

PortID = int

PortName = Varchar

ContryID = int

```
SELECT     dbo.tblPort.PortID, dbo.tblPort.PortName, dbo.tblPort.CountryID,   dbo.tblCountry.CountryName
FROM         dbo.tblCountry RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.tblPort ON dbo.tblCountry.CountryID = dbo.tblPort.CountryID
```